# dnf what build requires package foo?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

How can I find out which packages have a **build** requirement on some package `foo`?
I'm aware of the following command

```
dnf repoquery --alldeps --recursive --whatrequires foo
```

in order to query all packages which have a requirement on package `foo`.
However, packages with a **build** requirement only are not listed there. How can I list such packages, too?

Answer (score 3):

While build requirements are indeed not stored in the final RPM (as jsbillings pointed out) dnf was improved over the last years so you can actually query build requirements now.

```
dnf repoquery '--disablerepo=*' '--enablerepo=*-source' --arch=src \
      --whatrequires <provide>
```

Source: Examples in the [DNF Command Reference](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#examples) (at the very end of that section)

Comment: I've tested it with `python3-asynctest` and it seems to work. Perhaps it's worth noting that apparently one still has to specify a binary package name (e.g. `python3-asynctest` and not `python-asynctest`) but the command lists source packages (e.g. `python-aioresponses-0:0.6.3-1.fc31.src`).

Answer (score 1):

Build requirements aren't stored in the [RPM metadata](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-queryformat-tags.html) of a non-source RPM, so they would not be searchable by dnf.  You'd have to look at the .spec file used to build the RPM to find the BuildRequires: tags.

Comment: Oh that is a good point, though, sad to hear ;-) in that case I have to manually query spec files.